# How to customize a Qweb report properly by replacing "div[@class='page']"? Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I'm trying to customize a report_invoice_document qweb report. Here is the source code, So I'm trying to replace "div[@class='page']" and build my own report with the following code:

```
  <template id="report_invoice_extend" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
       <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/" position="replace">
                    <span>Customer Invoice Report</span>
               </xpath>
    </template>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/template_inheritance.py", line 132, in apply_inheritance_specs
    node = locate_node(source, spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/template_inheritance.py", line 58, in locate_node
    xPath = etree.ETXPath(expr)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 482, in lxml.etree.ETXPath.__init__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 423, in lxml.etree.XPath.__init__
  File "<string>", line None
lxml.etree.XPathSyntaxError: Invalid expression
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Try to remove the trailing slash in the xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

`expr="//div[@class='page']"` instead of `expr="//div[@class='page']/"`

Focus bro focus!

I know, working with the odoo system will absorb so much energy, but I wish you the best :)